# "order" does not affect order of custom query

Tags: query, order

This is my custom post type:

```
'label'               => __( 'Person', 'text_domain' ),
'description'         => __( 'Post Type Description', 'text_domain' ),
'labels'              => $labels,
'supports'            => array(
    'title',
    'thumbnail',
    'page-attributes'
),
'rewrite'             => array( 'slug' => 'personen_page'),
'hierarchical'        => false,
'public'              => true,
'show_ui'             => true,
'show_in_menu'        => true,
'menu_position'       => 5,
'menu_icon'           => 'dashicons-universal-access',
'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,
'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
'can_export'          => true,
'has_archive'         => true,
'exclude_from_search' => false,
'publicly_queryable'  => true,
'capability_type'     => 'post',
```

Works. In the template I want to show it with:

```
$args = array(
        'post_type'      => array( 'personen' ),
        'posts_per_page' => 99,
        'orderby'        => 'title',
        'order'          => 'DESC',
        'meta_query'     => array(
        'relation'       => 'IS',
        array(
            'value'     => '"' . get_the_ID() . '"',
            'compare'   => 'LIKE'
        )
    )
);
```

Works. Only problem: It makes no difference when using "**DESC**" (WordPress default) or "**AS**C". Wonder why!

Comment: What is the meta query supposed to be doing? You haven't specified a key, and `IS` is not a valid relation.

Comment: They have a relationship field (https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/relationship/).

Comment: Found the error, I have a function on top of this that sorts them by surname xD.